# Run Birt Eclipse BI Report on local server or online

Tags: eclipse, localhost, reporting, birt

i have created a Report using Birt Eclipse BI tools. But i am trying to display this report on local server or online . so every one can see this by browser. 
may it possible to run in browser in each machine of local.?
please report expert have a look.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide webbased access to the reports, you can have a look at the Enterprise Reporting Server. The project is up on GitHub at https://www.github.com/stephanfeb/ers and you can download a prebuilt .war from http://www.computonium.com

Stephan